# How do you group by values in a pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

I have a pivot table that shows percent of total value per item.  I need to be able to do 2 things:

1. Only show top 5 items where item 5 is a sum of all lesser values
2. Group values lesser than a specified tolerance

This has to be automatic because the pivot is connected to slicers which refresh based on filters.